# .htaccess redirect using special characters in RequestRule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to make redirect for all requests:

```
FROM
www.host.com/login_vk+(Http parameters) 

TO
www.host.com/#!/login_vk+(Http parameters)

Example:
```

www.host.com/login_vk?code=34234234 => www.host.com/#!/login_vk?code=34234234

The first problem is that # is a comment, and did not find information how to shield #. I tried Unicode, Askii, backslash and others but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using apache here, you want this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^login_vk$ /#!/login_vk?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Redirected page in this case is http://www.host.com/?code=sdfasdfasdfasd#!/login_vk?code=sdfasdfasdfasd. I am using this site to test http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/